# CSS error in application.css of twitter bootstrap when deploying to heroku, but my application.css file is bare! How can I find the error

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I am trying to adjust the CSS of the application I am deploying but when I run    rake assets: precompile  I get this message (same as the example, even with     --trace) :

```
C:\Sites\LaunchPage>rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
mkdir -p C:/Sites/LaunchPage/public/assets
rake aborted!
Invalid CSS after "  margin:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " 0;"
(in C:/Sites/LaunchPage/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):457
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Post your application.css

Comment: If after `margin:` a pseudo-class or -element is expected, that means it is read as a _selector_, not as a property. So most likely you have an error with your curly braces in your CSS – so that `margin:` is _outside_ of any `{…}` blocks.

Comment: @techvineet my application.css is as follows: `/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
`

Comment: @CBroe I checked through all my CSS and    `margin:` was always within the brackets.

Comment: Also I should mention that it app loads correctly locally